# Multi-Condition Ifs

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm wondering if there is any way to condense an if statement like this

```
if(i == i || x == i || y == i || z == i)
{
    code
}
```

to something like:

```
if(i || x || y || z ==i)
{
    code
}
```

I don't mean will the latter work, I know it wont, is there any function that works like that?

Comment: `i == i` will be `true` always.  Did you mean to compare `i` against 4 _other_ values?

Comment: I was just making up a quick example. I did mean to be comparing to see if one of 4 values was the one I was looking for.